# How can I ensure that Entity Framework will create an association in a many-to-many relationship instead of a new record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a problem with Entity Framework.... I don't know it well.

I am working on a seemingly simple task of **associating an existing contact** to a **new order** in a system I'm working on.  Contacts will always exist prior to being associated to the order.

Simplified database tables...

**Order**
OrderID
Status
Created

**Contact**
ContactID
FirstName
LastName

**ContactToOrderMap**
OrderID
ContactID

I've linked these two tables in the DbContext.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany<Contact>(a => a.Contacts)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(a =>
                    {
                        a.ToTable("ContactToOrderMap");
                        a.MapLeftKey("OrderID");
                        a.MapRightKey("ContactID");
                    });
```

I wrote a unit test that simply creates an order, a contact, adds the contact to a list member on the order and attempts to save.

```
// setup 
var order = new Order() { // initialize required fields };

// add a contact that already exists in the database
var orderContact = new Contact() { ID = 2 }; 
order.Contacts.Add(orderContact);

// call
logic.Save(ref order);
```

Eventually this order is saved after some unrelated business logic is performed...

```
// Add to collection
_db.Orders.Add(obj);
// Commit changes
_db.SaveChanges();
```

**>> Here I receive errors related to required database fields on the Contact table.**  Not what I'm looking for as I really just want to add an association record in the ContactToOrderMap table.

As a next step, I tried to retrieve the existing contacts from the database prior to saving the order.  This code's not super clean, but it should explain what I'm attempting.

```
    if (currentOrder.Contacts != null)
    {
        var matchedContacts = new List<Contact>();

        foreach (var con in currentOrder.Contacts)
        {
            matchedContacts.Add(_contactLogic.Get(con.ID));
        }

        currentOrder.Contacts.Clear();
        foreach (var item in matchedContacts)
        {
            currentOrder.Contacts.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This created the association, **but created a new Contact (new unique ID) as well.**

The goal is to create an association and a new order only, not create a new contact.

Any ideas or pointers to get me going in the right direction?

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Edit: Fixed code - renamed obj to currentOrder.

Comment: You seem to want two things: _ existing contact to a new order_ and _create an association only_. Which is the one you're after? And, what is `obj`?

Comment: @GertArnold You're right, I do want two things.  I want to create a new order and the association, but leave the contact table untouched.  "obj" is actually "currentOrder".  I was renaming in the post for clarity and missed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line

```
var orderContact = new Contact() { ID = 2 };
```

do

```
_db.Contacts.Attach(orderContact);
```

Now the contact is part of the context in an `Unchanged` state, and

```
order.Contacts.Add(orderContact);
```

will not change its state to `Added` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gert.  This reply, and my co-workers' comments, led me in the same direction.  My object wasn't being tracked.  I replaced my matchedContacts.Add(_contactLogic.Get(con.ID)) to one that used the database context directly at a lower level and it tracked it appropriately without creating a new Contact.

Comment: This is probably the preferred way to accomplish this but I wanted to point out that you can also query for contact with id of 2 and then add that to your order. The reason this works is because when you query for the contact it is now tracked, rather than simply creating a new `Contact` object with id of 2.

Comment: @Nick You're right, but this is a way to do it without that database round trip. The "new" contact is called a stub object. Of course it can only be done when the Id is known, not when e.g. only a contact name is known.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped us solve the issue.  We basically just looped through our order's contacts and called Attach() on each contact, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for helping a new EF user.